# Не выводится информация c Table View Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple

Код View Controller

```
   import UIKit
   import Firebase
   import FirebaseDatabase
   import FirebaseAuth
   import SideMenu



class StocksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var Activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var db: FIRDatabaseReference!
var roomsDictionary: NSDictionary?

var needRandomizedRooms = true
var roomKeysArray: NSMutableArray? = []
var mainSearchBar: UISearchBar?
var mainNavigationTitleView: UIView?
var mainRightBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem?
var roomKeysArrayForTable:[String] = []

let seporator = "     "

var showOnly = "All"
let showOnlyNetwork = "network"
let showOnlyGenre = "genre"
var stringForSampling = ""

//MARK: - Lifecycle

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Акции"

    self.Activity.startAnimating()

    self.db = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
        self.getDatabase()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "stock")
        FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "rooms")
    }
}
func getDatabase () {

    if AppData.sharedInstance.city == nil {
    }
    else {
        self.showExcusesAlert()
    }

    self.tableview.isHidden = true
    self.Activity.startAnimating()

    self.db.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        AppData.sharedInstance.needUpdateData = false

        AppData.sharedInstance.database = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        self.roomsDictionary = AppData.getRooms()

        self.Activity.stopAnimating()
        self.tableview.isHidden = false

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func showExcusesAlert() {
    if AppData.sharedInstance.showExcusesMessage == true {
        AppData.sharedInstance.showExcusesMessage = false
        //self.showAlert(message: "Приложение находится в стадии разработки. Приносим извинения за возможные временные трудности при работе с приложением")
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! RoomViewController

    let name = self.roomKeysArrayForTable[(self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]

    let dicti = self.roomsDictionary?[name] as! NSDictionary

    AppData.sharedInstance.roomName = name as String?

    vc.dataDictionary = dicti

}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.roomKeysArrayForTable.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StocksTableViewCell.cellIdentifier1(), for: indexPath) as! StocksTableViewCell

        let name = self.roomKeysArrayForTable[indexPath.row]
        if self.roomsDictionary != nil {
            let dict1 = self.roomsDictionary?[name] as! NSDictionary

            cell.stocksViewController = self
            cell.configureCell1(name: name, dictionary: dict1)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Код ViewControllerCell

```
     import UIKit
     import FirebaseStorage
     import Firebase
     import SDWebImage


     class StocksTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var BorderView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Description: UILabel!


var lastX: CGFloat  = 16.0
var stepX: CGFloat = 0.0

var stocksViewController: StocksViewController!
var nameRoom = ""


static func cellIdentifier1 () -> String {
    return "StocksTableViewCell"
}

func configureCell1 (name: String, dictionary: NSDictionary) {

    self.nameRoom = name

    self.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder_image")

    self.NameLabel.text = name.uppercased()

    UICustomizeHelper.roundCornersForView(view: self.BorderView)

    let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let reference = storageRef.child("stocks/"+name+".jpg")

    if let cacheUrl = AppData.sharedInstance.cacheRoomImagePathDictionary[name] {
        self.ImageView.sd_setImage(with: cacheUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder_image"))
    }
    else {

        reference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            AppData.sharedInstance.cacheRoomImagePathDictionary[name] = url
            self.ImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder_image"))
        }
    }
    (self.subviews as NSArray).enumerateObjects(options: NSEnumerationOptions.reverse) { (value, index, nil) in
        if self.subviews[index].tag == 545 {
            self.subviews[index].removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

 }
```

Comment: Не очень хорошая практика когда UITableViewCell что является View работает напрямую с Model. Если речь идет об MVC.

Comment: Где у Вас UITableView DataSource?

Answer (score -1):

Надо отладку делать в runtime, точки останова, проверка содержания переменных,  и т.п. Первым проверить что там в self.roomsDictionary в методе cellForRowAt indexPath, если данные есть, пошагово проверять, там не так уж и много, если нет - смотреть почему данных нет. Код конечно не фонтан, но работать должен по идее.